# ROR - The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

When i upload my ROR code in server and run my website that time i face this type of error.

```
The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application.
Because you are running this web application in staging or production mode
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the mode of environment in nginx configuration.

```
server{
     listen 80 default_server;
     passenger_enabled on;
     passenger_app_env production;
     root <path to application folder>;
}
```

If you see passenger_app_env is set to production.

For more details, could you please share the nginx error logs ?